# @nestjs/graphql working with typeORM custom many to many relation

Tags: graphql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a problem getting a user with roles and adding roles to a user using [@nestjs/graphql](https://github.com/nestjs/graphql). We have a custom property in usersToRoles(junction entity).

**User entity:**

```
@Entity()
export class Users {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  user_id: string;
  ...
  @OneToMany(() => UsersToRoles, (usersToRoles) => usersToRoles.user)
  usersToRoles!: UsersToRoles[];
}
```

**Role entity:**

```
@Entity()
export class Roles {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  role_id: string;
  ...

  @OneToMany(() => UsersToRoles, (usersToRoles) => usersToRoles.role)
  usersToRoles!: UsersToRoles[];
}
```

**UsersToRoles(Junction entity)**

```
@Entity()
export class UsersToRoles {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public userToRolesId!: number;

  @Column()
  public user_id!: string;

  @Column()
  public role_id!: string;

  @Column()
  public app_id!: string; // this needs to be polymorphic

  @ManyToOne(() => Users, (user) => user.usersToRoles)
  @JoinColumn({name: 'user_id'})
  public user!: Users;

  @ManyToOne(() => Roles, (roles) => roles.usersToRoles)
  @JoinColumn({name: 'role_id'})
  public role!: Roles;
}
```

How can I add addRolesToUser using graphql and fetch user with his/her roles?

Comment: What is the part you don't understand? Is it the graphQL request or the typeorm query?

Comment: For TypeORM can we have polymorphism? For graphql after we achieve typeorm polymorphism does nestjs-graphql support adding and removing these polymorphic relations?